# Libgdx - How to Clean a Color?

Tags: java, colors, libgdx

I'm trying to paint some images. I'm using sprites and `setColor`, but, when I try to paint the image to white, doesn't work. It keeps the last color. I also try use `Color.CLEAR` and later paint to white, but it doesn't work. So, how can i do it?

Comment: Please provide some code you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sprite#setColor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setColor%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color%29) method, sets the Color that will be used to tint the sprite when rendered with [SpriteBatch](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html).

The default color is white, if you set the color to white again, what you are doing is rendering the image exactly as it is (i.e. No tint).